# BeautifulSoup cannot extract item using find_all()

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I am try to get the location of text from HTML like below using BeautfulSoup,here are my html:

```
<p><em>code of Drink<br></em>
Budweiser: 4BDB1CD96<br>
price: 10$</p>
```

with codes:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
result = re.escape('4BDB1CD96')
tag = soup.find(['li','div','p','em'],string=re.compile(result))
```

I cannot extract tag,but where I changed the find_all() into:
tag = soup.find(string=re.compile(result))
then I can get the result:
Budweiser: 4BDB1CD96
So I want to know why and how to get the result like in tag fromat

Comment: I solving it by  replace all <em></em> with ' ' ,but i still want to know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your tags have nested tags, and the text you are searching for is inside such a tag (`p` here).

So, the easiest approach is to use a lambda inside `.find()` to check tag names and if there `.text` property contains your pattern. Here, you do not even need a regex:

```
>>> tag = soup.find(lambda t: t.name in ['li','div','p','em'] and '4BDB1CD96' in t.text)
>>> tag
<p><em>code of Drink<br/></em>
Budweiser: 4BDB1CD96<br/>
price: 10$</p>
>>> tag.string
>>> tag.text
'code of Drink\nBudweiser: 4BDB1CD96\nprice: 10$'
```

Of course, you may use a regex for more complex searches:

```
r = re.compile('4BDB1CD96') # or whatever the pattern is
tag = soup.find(lambda t: t.name in ['li','div','p','em'] and r.search(t.text))
```